# Configuration page for module does not apear?

Tags: 7

This is my hook_menu.

```
function coverflow_menu(){
        $items = array();

        $items['coverflow']  = array(
            'title'           => 'Coverflow Slider',
            'page callback'     => 'coverflow_page',
            'access arguments'=> array('access content'),
        );

        $items['admin/config/coverflow'] = array(
                'title'                 => 'Coverflow Settings',
                'description'         => 'Coverflow Slider Settings.',
                'type'                  => 'MENU_NORMAL_ITEM',
                'page callback'     => 'drupal_get_form',
                'page arguments'    => array('coverflow_admin_form'),
                'access arguments'=> array('administer site configuration'),
                'file'            => 'coverflow_admin_form.inc',
                'file path'       => drupal_get_path('module', 'coverflow'),
            );

        return $items;
   }
```

And this is my callback function for coverflow_admin_form

```
function coverflow_admin_form($form, &$form_state){

    $form           = array();

    $form['height'] = array(
      '#title' => t('Height'),
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#size' => 40,
      '#maxlength' => 120,
      '#required' => TRUE,
    );  

    $form['width'] = array(
      '#title' => t('Width'),
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#size' => 40,
      '#maxlength' => 120,
      '#required' => TRUE,
    );

    $form['font-size'] = array(
      '#title' => t('Font Size'),
      '#type'   => 'textfield',
      '#size'   => 40,
      '#maxlength' => 120,
      '#required' => TRUE,
    );

    $form['font-family'] = array(
      '#title' => t('Font Family'),
      '#type'   => 'textfield',
      '#size'   => 40,
      '#maxlength' => 120,
      '#required' => TRUE,
    );

    $form['font-color'] = array(
      '#title' => t('Font Color'),
      '#type'   => 'textfield',
      '#size'   => 40,
      '#maxlength' => 120,
      '#required' => TRUE,
    );

    $form['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Save settings'),
    );

        return system_settings_form($form);

}
```

After installing module im not getting configuration link at admin/config/coverflow.

What is wrong in this code?

Comment: Url for configuration page is not correct. It should be `admin/config/development/coverflow` or `admin/config/content/coverflow` or for any other section in admin.

Comment: ok let me try this option.

Comment: after changing admin/config/coverflow to admin/config/development/coverflow, my hook_menu link is disappear and complete code is not working.

Comment: Have you clear the cache and test it?

Comment: yes after updating module files, im clearing cache and sometimes uninstalling module and then installing again to check updates. but still its not working.

Comment: How do i debug module file step by step to check where is the actual problem, Is there any technique for debugging module.

Comment: you can use `debug` module to debug site. I have to install your module into my test serve and then let you know.

Comment: ok thanx i will try to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution, just have to remove '' from 'MENU_NORMAL_ITEM' because MENU_NORMAL_ITEM is drupal constant for handling Menu Items, after removing '' the code is working as expected.

Comment: I was also adding the same as my answer. But your url was also not proper for configuration page.